# JS/Jquery, Match not finding the PNG = match('/gif|jpg|jpeg|png/')

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, match

I have the following code which I use to match fancybox possible elements:

```
$('a.grouped_elements').each(function(){
    var elem = $(this);
    // Convert everything to lower case to match smart
    if(elem.attr('href').toLowerCase().match('/gif|jpg|jpeg|png/') != null) {
        elem.fancybox();
    }
});
```

It works great with JPGs but it isn't matching PNGs for some reason. Anyone see a bug with the code?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show real world examples of URLs that don't, and do get matched?

Comment: As an aside, why are you using `.toLowerCase()` instead of the `i` (case-insensitive) regex modifier?  The `!= null` part is also superfluous, since you're not type checking and `match()` will only return a falsey value when there's no match.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A couple of things.

Match accepts an object of `RegExp`, not a string. It may work in some browsers, but is definitely not standard.

```
"gif".match('/gif|png|jpg/'); // null​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Without the strings

```
"gif".match(/gif|png|jpg/); // ["gif"]
```

Also, you would want to check these at the end of a filename, instead of anywhere in the string.

```
"isthisagif.nope".match(/(gif|png|jpg|jpeg)/); // ["gif", "gif"]
```

Only searching at the end of string with $ suffix

```
"isthisagif.nope".match(/(gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/); // null
```

No need to make href lowercase, just do a case insensitive search `/i`.

Look for a dot before the image extension as an additional check.

[And some tests.](http://jsfiddle.net/qMHmZ/) I don't know how you got any results back with using a string argument to `.match`. What browser are you on?

Comment: This also matches 'giffffff'. Would you be able to make it work only for the actual words 'gif', 'png' etc?

Comment: @meow - which particular regex are you referring to for `gifffff`, and I didn't get the second part of the question.

Comment: Sorry, this one "isthisagif.nope".match(/(gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/); it would match isthisagif.gif, but also, isthisagit.gifwhatever. I was wondering if you could modify it so it only matches isthisagif.gif (and nothing else)

Comment: @meow - so you mean the file *must* end in `.gif`?

Comment: yes exactly, only the words that specified (gif, png, jpg, jpeg)

Comment: try the last one - `/\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/`. It says that there must be a dot followed by either of these four extensions and that should be the end of the string.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the fact that it'll match anywhere in the string (it would match "http://www.giftshop.com/" for instance) could be considered a bug. I'd use

```
/\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string to the match() function rather than a regular expression.  In JavaScript, strings are delimited with single quotes, and regular expressions are delimited with forward slashes.  If you use both, you have a string, not a regex.

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly for me: `/.+\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/i`

`.+` -> any string

`\.` -> followed by a point.

`(gif|png|jpe?g)` -> and then followed by any of these extensions. jpeg may or may not have the letter e.

`$` -> now the end of the string it's expected

`/i` -> case insensitive mode: matches both `sflkj.JPG` and `lkjfsl.jpg`