# Regex jquery the proper way

Tags: jquery, validation, special-characters, string-matching

I am trying to do a few form validation checks and I am facing some problems. First of all could some one tell me is the match function the right way to check a string. Secondly could some one explain why is this not working and what is the right format. I am trying to check if there is anything except alphabets (Letters) It works fine for numbers and returns an error but if i type (.) / ; etc anything except a number it allows and no error is reported.

```
  if ($("#firstname").val().match(/[a-zA-Z]/))
```

I want to only allow alphabets nothing else. One more thing this confuses me alot if there is a match the error will go in else right? For instance.

```
   if ($("#firstname").val().match(/[a-zA-Z]/))
   {  // no match carry on... }else

   {/ found match display error }
```

Thanks help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/`.

At present you're merely *searching* for an alphabetic character in the string, not searching for a string that is comprised only of them.

As for your second question, of course `match` succeeds if a match was found, so your conditional handling is backwards.

```
if ($("#firstname").val().match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
   // string contains only alphabetcharacters
}
else {
   // non-alphabet characters found, or string was empty
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should work:

```
if ($("#firstname").val().match(/^([a-zA-Z])*$/))
```

Answer (score 0):

About `match()`, look at this answer to other question:
[JS/Jquery, Match not finding the PNG = match('/gif|jpg|jpeg|png/')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575685/js-jquery-match-not-finding-the-png-match-gifjpgjpegpng/2575757#2575757)